# bounded derivate

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

Given a dynamical system $\dot{x}=f(x)$ with bounded solutions, i.e. $\Vert x\Vert \le c$, with  $c<\infty$. Then, $\dot{x}$ is bounded if $f(x)$ is bounded. I wonder if there are less restrictive condition on the function $f(x)$ (conditions that do not rely on the boundedness of $f(\cdot)$) allowing to conclude that $\dot{x}$ is bounded.

Comment: Perhaps I'm completely misunderstanding your question, but since $\dot{x} = f(x)$, being bounded is **equivalent** for the two functions.

Comment: That is right, I am wondering if there are other conditions on the function $f(\cdot)$ (excluding the case where $f$ is bounded) such that $dx/dt$ is bounded given that $x$ is bounded

Comment: I think you're missing a crucial detail here. If $f$ is not bounded on the ball of radius $c$, then $\dot{x}$ is not bounded, because $f(x)$ and $\dot{x}$ are the same thing. Unless you mean to specify an initial condition and ask whether $f(x)$ is bounded along the forward orbit through that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it's quite easy to give an example where $f$ is unbounded, but *all* orbits are bounded; the most straightforward one is
\begin{align}
 \dot{x} &= y,\\
 \dot{y} &= -x,
\end{align}
i.e. the harmonic oscillator with unit frequency.

In this case, the boundedness of the orbits is a direct consequence of the fact that the above system is *conservative*.

For non-conservative (i.e. dissipative) systems, the question 'which orbits are bounded' is tantamount to fully understanding the state space of the system, in particular its *attractors*. This is in general a highly nontrivial exercise. I would recommend to read the [Scholarpedia article on 'Basin of attraction'](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Basin_of_attraction) and the [Wikipedia article on 'Attractor'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attractor); the lemma at [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Attractor.html) also gives some useful information. For a more general take on conservative systems, see the [Scholarpedia article on Hamiltonian systems](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Hamiltonian_systems).